# Import Error on importing pydrake.multibody.math

Tags: python, drake

I'm trying to import `SpatialForce` for my code but it keeps failing with the error

```
ImportError: C++ type is not registered in pybind: N5Eigen14AutoDiffScalarINS_6MatrixIdLin1ELi1ELi0ELin1ELi1EEEEE
```

Simply running

```
from pydrake.multibody.math import SpatialForce
```

or

```
import pydrake.multibody.math
```

in a python interpreter causes this error.  Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: If I import `pydrake.math` before running these imports, the problem goes away.

Comment: Can you describe which version of Drake you're using? https://drake.mit.edu/getting_help.html#helpful-information And can you try ensuring that nothing else is on your path? https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13187

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought this was just isolated to `pydrake.math`, didn't read it carefully enough. Will debug now.

Comment: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/14071

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it in the following PR: 
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/14072

(Also added in a new test to try and catch things like this in the future!)

Thanks!